# Assigning value to int passed by reference stops program execution

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

```
void assignVal(int *loopCount)
{
    //lots of stuff with print statements to know where func stop executing

    cout << "before assign resultCount" << endl;

    *loopCount = 3; //I want the loopSize int in the main function to be equal to 3;

    cout << "after assign resultCount" << endl;

    return;
}

int main() 
{
    int loopSize;

    assignVal(&loopSize);
    //Doesn't get here or below
    for(int i = 0; i < loopSize; i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass in the variable `loopSize` to be assigned inside the function `assignVal(int*)`.  I have no control over the main function, this is for hackerank (this is obviously not the code from the problem, i am just showing a heavily modified version of the small part that isn't working for me.  I also have no control of the `assignVal(int*)` function signature.  I need to receive this int*, change it within the function, and then just return.  I don't know why this isn't working, this is how I would do it anywhere else.  The `cout` "after assign resultCount" never gets printed, and the program stops executing there.  I can confirm it IS compiling.

Edit:  It should be noted that if I assign `loopCount` like this

```
int* arr = {3};
loopCount = arr;
```

The function continues to execute just fine, but the value outside the function is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: It seems something is wrong inside the "lots of stuff with print statements to know where func stop executing"

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0da28ff938b782ec)

Comment: @Pezzza There's not, i have print statements in there to see that everything is going smoothly.  Even the value I am assigning to `loopCount` is what it should be, but as soon as I assign it, it stops.  See Edit Also

Comment: It seems they are expecting an array of ints

Comment: That wouldn't really make sense, since `loopSize` is declared as `int` and it's used like `i < loopSize`

Comment: Test in a debugger, step by step. Does something change the pointer value? Does something delete it? Does something corrupt the stack/heap?

Comment: @user11392753 can you send a link to the Hackerank problem ?

Comment: @user11392753 Your edited `loopCount = arr` sets the pointer itself, it isn't setting the data being originally pointed to.

Comment: right @FireLancer , I was just trying to add extra info, i know it won't work.  What I am trying initially should be working I just don't know why it isn't.

Comment: @Pezzza I can't, it's private :/

Comment: You should still be able to make a runnable example of the problem. Did you change the pointer at all? If not possibly stack corruption.

Answer (score 0):

It is not passed by reference, it is a pointer. Raw pointers need careful management to avoid problems. You can pass by reference like this:

```
void assignVal(int & loopCount)
```

You can read more here:
[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)